# Change/Add hierarchy of work elements/backlog elements

Tags: azure-devops, configuration

Im starting to work with Azure DevOps and i got the task to change the hierarchy of the backlogs.

I want to add another hierarchy layer between the Feature Level and the Requirements Level.

Is there a way to configure Azure DevOps that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into this doc for [customizing backlogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=azure-devops), follow the route of organization_setting --> Process --> Traget_process --> Backlog_levels, and you could choose to add a new backlog level or manage other layers.
[image]

Once you finish the settings above, you could check out your customization in backlogs of boards with screenshots below. You could choose the layers that displaying in your backlogs.

[image]
[image]

Bug-type are usually not displaying in the backlogs, but you could [change the settings](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2014729) to display it in requirement level of Stories.